# Using List inside a postgres Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a  dynamic list.

`list=['a','b','c','d' ..... ]`  so length may change

i want to compare these list values in a query

```
select * from student where name in(all the list values);
```

i want to pass list values into this query

how i can do this.. ???  please help
Thank you

Comment: are you using a program language to generate the SQL and to get the dynamic list? Which one?

Comment: Where does the `list` comes from?

Comment: LIST is actually a location list... 
i want to filter my select query according to the value in the LIST..
List is generated from front end checkbox

Comment: What is your programming language? What is the sample code?

Comment: In JAVA

List<String> loc_list= new ArrayList<String>();
loc_list.add("Bangalore");
loc_list.add("pune");
.(its dynamic can be more)

String sql1 = "select * from tbl_meeting where location in ( loc_list) ";

how i can  get all data from that belongs to location which are present in that LOC_LIST

Comment: You need to concatenate the array list with comma separated and finally merge it with your sql.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can use arrays.  The syntax in the `where` clause looks like:

```
where name = any (array[1, 2, 3])
```

or

```
where name = any (list_parameter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that gets a list as a parameter and return a string like "'one', 'two','three'".

```
    // need a string like this 'one', 'two'
    private String arrayToSqlInChecker(List<String> loc_list) {
        StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i < loc_list.size(); i++) {
            value.append("'" + loc_list.get(i) + "'");
            if (i != loc_list.size() - 1) {
                value.append(",");
            }
        }
        return value.toString();
    }
```

And then you have to append this string into you PostgreSQL IN query

```
"id IN (" + this.arrayToSqlInChecker(loc_list) + ")"
```

You can also handle null or empty values in the function